# jQuery blur() or focusout() not firing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, focus, blur

So I have this form and I would like to do some stuff when the inputs loose focus. This is the code I have and it's working like a champ in every browser except Internet Explorer.

```
function formstyle() {

    var focus = 0;

    //comentario is the ID of the input
    $("#comentario").focus(function() {
        //blablablabla
    });

    $("#comentario").blur(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var whatFocus = document.activeElement.tagName;

            if (whatFocus === "BODY") {
                focus = 0;
                //bla bla bla
            }
        }, 2);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    formstyle();
});
```

I'm almost blowing up my mind. It's a simple piece of code and yet… nothing… Did I miss anything?

Comment: What error do you get in IE? What version of IE?

Comment: Which version of jQuery, and which version of IE? jQuery v2.x.x doesn't support IE < 9.

Comment: @MikeW: Pretty sure is IE9+.

Comment: @elclanrs - You're quite right. - edited

Comment: Oh sorry about that lack of information. 

This happens in every IE. And the jQuery version is 1.10.1

As for the errors. Strangely it throws a couple of syntax errors in the jQuery code (from google) but no errors on this code… I think my IE installation is a bit crazy… 

The jQuery errors it gives are in: e.querySelectorAll(*,:x") and y.call(e,"[s!='']:x").



Yet, i have use focusout in another function in the same website and IE runs it well… :/

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using focusout? http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

```
$("#comentario").focusout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    var whatFocus = document.activeElement.tagName;

    if(whatFocus === "BODY")
    {
        focus = 0;
        //bla bla bla
    }
    }, 2);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And yup. Same thing… I also used on() to no avail.

Comment: what about if you select with: $('comentario').find('input')

Comment: That way it doesn't work in any browser. :) #comentario is already the input. But i've tried with the parent element and still no luck. This is frustrating. I have another function with blur() and it works great.

Comment: $('#comentario').on('focusout', function() {
   //bla bla bla

});

Answer (score 0):

Oky… After hours trying every idea, even the the most strange ones, with no luck, i asked my gf for her computer and so i tried it there and all worked like a charm… :/ Pretty weird…

I just had to add a "DIV" part to the if conditional block to make the code inside it to work in IE9 and bellow, but the "focusout" thingy worked on the other computer with no issues.

I'm guessing my IE installation has some problems. Can't see any other explanation.

Anyway, thanks for all the help guys!