# JQuery blur event not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blur

I've got follow code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let element = $('.inputField');
  element.on({
    'input': function(e) {
      console.log('input');
    },
    'blur': function(e) {
      console.log('blur');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="inputField">
<input>
<button>Click here</button>
```

I use two `events` on my `input`. The first event is the `input`. I use this to detect if something was written in my input. The second one is the `blur`. With this event I detect if the `focus` on my input was lost (for example with tab into next input) or if the user clicked outside the input (for example on the button). Now this works fine on `chrome`. I also need it on `internet explorer`, but there the blur doesn't work. I looked at this questions:

[jQuery blur event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703433/jquery-blur-event-not-firing)

[jQuery blur() or focusout() not firing in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073602/jquery-blur-or-focusout-not-firing-in-internet-explorer)

[Blur event not working in IE11 and IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328736/blur-event-not-working-in-ie11-and-ie10)

I could not find a solution to my problem. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Umh... IE doesn't support ES6 arrow functions, older IEs are not supporting any ES6 features.

Comment: An arrow function with a single statement does not need curly brackets, e.g. it should be `'input': (e) => console.log('input', e)`

Comment: I tried it and it's working on IE 11.
https://gyazo.com/825344ceacaf38c633277786fa977c00

Comment: @Teemu It also doesn't work without arrow functions...

Comment: Your fixed Stack snippet seems to log "blur" every time I leave for `#inputField`, when I run the snippet in IE11. Older IEs don't understand anything about ES6, though.

Comment: Hi, I found the error. This input is transcluded by a ng-component with an own binding called disabled. I renamed it because the html attr disabled allready exists, so it was a error because of this... Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ES5 syntax replace ES6.